# Const member init

Tags: c++, c++11

In my book "The C++ Programming Language" Bjarne Stroustrup I'm read about const members init and saw the next code (i change var names and values):

```
class ConstMembers
{
public:
    static const int a = 1; // ok
    static int b = 2; // error: non const
    const int c = 3; // error: no static
    static const float d = 2.3; // error: not integer
};
```

But when i run this code in Clion 2020.1 with next cmake setting

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

in third case

```
const int c = 3; // error: no static
```

i didn't get an error.

[image: clion screen]

It is an error in the book or the c++11 allows such initialization?

Comment: What edition are you reading? It was updated for C++11 with the 4th edition I believe.

Comment: I read the translated book  (In Russian). written "Special edition" 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 allows that. Your book must be old. See [Non-static data members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [default initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) was supported since C++11.

(emphasis mine)

> Through a default member initializer, which is **a brace or equals
>   initializer** included in the member declaration and is used if the
>   member is omitted from the member initializer list of a constructor.
>
> If a member has a default member initializer and also appears in the
>   member initialization list in a constructor, the default member
>   initializer is ignored for that constructor.

You can also initialize it as

```
class ConstMembers
{
public:
    ...
    const int c {3};
    ...
};
```